# Pi shuts down after few minutes

Tags: pi-3

My raspberry pi 3 works for a few minutes but then shuts down and the green and red LED become solid. I have checked the power cable with a multimeter and have tried different SD cards. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the CPU get very hot very quickly?  If so your Pi is probably bust beyond repair.